# Writing a loop to a file

Tags: python

Hey guys I am new to python I’m in year 11 so I’m still learning I wrote a code that loops the questions of asking what the useres name is their age and year group and then prints out a username containing their first 3 letters of their name and their year group then age ? 
I was wondering how I could write all of these usernames into a file I use a for loop to repeat the question 5 times to ask 5 different users and now I want to know how to store their user names into a file I know how to store an input but not this type of problem

Comment: This feels like a class assignment. What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I have gotten everything write apart from the writing to file I have got the code working so it ask the user for their name age and year group 5 times and prints their username now I need to write these usernames to a file?

Comment: first you have to open a file hander `output_file= open("./usernames.txt", "w")` and then instead of using simple `print(username)` use `print("test", file=output)`

Answer (score 0):

You can save data to a file in Python by opening a `file` object in write mode. To do this, you would use the built-in `open()` function, which returns a file object. The `open()` function accepts a number of possible arguments, but the two you are interested in are the filename and mode. As an example of the usage:

```
file = open("your_filename_here.txt", "w")
```

This opens a file object named `your_filename_here.txt` in *write mode*, indicated by passing `"w"` as the second argument of the function. From here, you can write the usernames to this file using the `write()` function of the `file` object:

```
username = "your_username_here"
file.write(username + "\n")
```

Where the `\n` newline character at the end ensures that each username is assigned to its own line within the text file.

This call to the `write()` function can then be put into your `for` loop to write each username to the file. Once the loop completes, you can then call the `close()` function of the `file` object to close the file.

```
file.close()
```

As a prototype from your description of the program, the whole process would look something like this:

```
# Opens a new or existing file named "usernames.txt".
file = open("usernames.txt", "w")

# Assigns the number of users.
users = 5

# Loops once for each user.
for user in range(users):

    # Collects user's name, year group, and age.
    name = input("Enter your name:       ")
    year = input("Enter your year group: ")
    age  = input("Enter your age:        ")

    # Creates a username for the user.
    username = name[0:3] + year + age

    # Prints the username.
    print("Username: " + username + "\n")

    # Writes the username to the file.
    file.write(username + "\n")

# Closes the file.
file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you everyone very much